# How can I retrieve elements in a multidimensional pytorch tensor by a list of indices?

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors: `scores` and `lists` 
`scores` is of shape `(x, 8)` and `lists` of `(x, 8, 4)`. I want to filter the max values for each row in `scores` **and filter the respective elements from** `lists`.

Take the following as an example (shape dimension `8` was reduced to `2` for simplicity):

```
scores = torch.tensor([[0.5, 0.4], [0.3, 0.8], ...])
lists = torch.tensor([[[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5],
                       [0.4, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2]], 
                      [[0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3], 
                       [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5]], ...])
```

Then I would like to filter these tensors to:

```
scores = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.8, ...])
lists = torch.tensor([[0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5], ...])
```

**NOTE:**
I tried so far, to retrieve the indices from the original score vector and use it as an index vector to filter lists:

```
# PSEUDO-CODE
indices = scores.argmax(dim=1)
for list, idx in zip(lists, indices):
    list = list[idx]
```

That is also where the question name is coming from.

Comment: [LGremetieri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760695/2790047) is correct, but as a comment, it's probably worth reading through the [numpy advanced indexing docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) since pytorch implements the same indexing semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you tried something like

```py
indices = scores.argmax(dim=1)
selection = lists[:, indices]
```

This does not work because the indices are selected for every element in dimension 0, so the final shape is `(x, x, 4)`.

The perform the correct selection you need to replace the slice with a range.

```py
indices = scores.argmax(dim=1)
selection = lists[range(indices.size(0)), indices]
```